# Codeigniter MY Loader View Change

Tags: php, codeigniter

On my loader.php in codeigniter. I would like my modules to be able to set there own view paths I can not seem to be able to get it working with all three paths.

How would I best be able to make it work. It only works with one path at the moment.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

    function __construct() {
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'modules/install/views/template/' => TRUE);
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'modules/admin/views/template/' => TRUE);
            $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'modules/catalog/views/template/theme' => TRUE);
          $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
            $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
          $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
          log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");

    }

}
```

**Current**

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

    function __construct() {
    $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'modules/install/views/template/' => TRUE);

    $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
    $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
    $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
    log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to be able to choose view paths is to make it as an array. If use MX Codeigniter HMVC. It works fine I just have tested it out.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/MX/Loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

    function __construct() {
        $this->_ci_view_paths = array(
            APPPATH . 'modules/install/views/template/' => TRUE,
            APPPATH . 'modules/admin/views/template/' => TRUE,
            APPPATH . 'modules/catalog/views/template/theme' => TRUE
        );
       $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
       $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
       $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
       log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");
    }

}
```